# Animating material icons to transform: Hamburger to X

Tags: angular, angular-material, icons, angular-animations

Long time reader, first-time poster. 
I want to have a material hamburger transform to an "X" when clicked and then transform back when clicked again in an Angular application. The website https://material.io/design/iconography/animated-icons.html#transitions
shows there are animations just like what I want, but there are no docs on how to do it.

I tried a CSS approach but it is not showing and it would be good to keep the project consistent with the material icons.

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
</button>

CSS

navbar-toggle {
  border: none;
  background: transparent !important;

  &:hover {
    background: transparent !important;
  }

  .icon-bar {
    width: 22px;
    transition: all 0.2s;
  }
  .top-bar {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: 10% 10%;
  }
  .middle-bar {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .bottom-bar {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: 10% 90%;
  }
}

.navbar-toggle.collapsed {
  .top-bar {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  .middle-bar {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .bottom-bar {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
}
```

The above code is a workaround to the material icons. When I run the above code, I get a transparent button with no animations. If anyone knows how to do a transition from a hamburger to an "X" in angular with bootstrap, I would be very grateful.

Comment: As mentioned in this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325400/angular-4-animated-icons), there isn't any documentation because the site is just showing what you 'could' do with the icons.You'll have to experiment with it and find something you're happy with. Here are some resources that could prove useful: https://cloudcannon.com/deconstructions/2014/12/05/material-design-delightful-details.html. | 
https://medium.com/@beeman/animate-font-awesome-icons-in-angular-2823474e0d22

Answer (score 6):

I made this simple [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-hamburguer-animation) using just `Angular` animations (no bootstrap) that still needs some work in the `CSS` of the states of the animation to make it nice and smooth but you can get the idea.

Create 3 bars wrapped in a container

```html
<div (click)="onClick()" class="btn">
  <div class="icon-bar" [@hamburguerX]="isHamburguer ? 'hamburguer' : 'topX'"></div>
  <div class="icon-bar" [@hamburguerX]="isHamburguer ? 'hamburguer' : 'hide'"></div>
  <div class="icon-bar" [@hamburguerX]="isHamburguer ? 'hamburguer' : 'bottomX'"></div>
</div>
```

style your bars and cursor

```
.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 20px;
}

.icon-bar {
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  margin: 3px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Add animation to the those 3 bars to run on click

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('hamburguerX', [
      /*
        state hamburguer => is the regular 3 lines style.
        states topX, hide, and bottomX => used to style the X element
      */
      state('hamburguer', style({})),
      // style top bar to create the X
      state(
        'topX',
        style({
          transform: 'rotate(45deg)',
          transformOrigin: 'left',
          margin: '6px',
        })
      ),
      // hides element when create the X (used in the middle bar)
      state(
        'hide',
        style({
          opacity: 0,
        })
      ),
      // style bottom bar to create the X
      state(
        'bottomX',
        style({
          transform: 'rotate(-45deg)',
          transformOrigin: 'left',
          margin: '6px',
        })
      ),
      transition('* => *', [
        animate('0.2s'), // controls animation speed
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
})
export class AppComponent {
  // flag be consumed by the template
  isHamburguer = true;
  onClick() {
    this.isHamburguer = !this.isHamburguer;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This combined with a docs review really helped me to create an amazing animation! Thank you again for your help!